# How many bit strings oft length k have more than one 1?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question seems rather simple, but I am not able to get a closed formula.

e.g.
for k=2 it is 1 (11), 
for k=3 it is 4 (111,101,110,011)

I thought that it maybe could be $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^k $ but I don't know how to prove it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the number of strings with no $1$s? And with just one $1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $2^k$ minus the number of strings with no $1$s or just one $1$.

There's one string with no $1$s: the one with all zeroes.

There's $k$ strings with just one $1$: $1$ located in the $i$th spot, with $1 \leq i \leq k$, and the rest zeroes.

So,  $f(k) = 2^k - k - 1.$